# Docker - run deployed asp.net application

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

How to run this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
c2cafa3cb28b        voiconshop:dev      "tail -f /dev/null"      8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        5000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32769->80/tcp    dockercompose5647427199741822447_voiconshop_1
a14af67cb5f1        e898d5096181        "dotnet VoiConShop..."   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          8889/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->2000/tcp   loving_volhard
```

I opened Chrome then enter: http://localhost:8889/ or http://localhost:5000/

However, the site can't reached.

Comment: Docker is listening to port 8889 and 8080, not 5000. Also internally it redirects 8080 to 2000. On which port does your application run? How have you configured it? Did you use the docker template from Visual Studio 2017 or did you created it yourself? You have to provide much more information if you want people help you. The ASP.NET COre docker templates from VS2017 usually works out of the box